# Everything disappeared from ubuntu desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, python, dpkg

I am posting this question from my phone as I am not able to access taskbar or any apps in the laptop(ubuntu 16.04, 64-bit).

After googling it I found this command

```
mv ~/.cache/compizconfig-1 ~/.cache/compizconfig-renamed
shutdown -r 0
```

Which did not work.

After which I tried to reinstall unity

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Which gave me following error

> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)

Then I tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Which gave me dpkg error

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

After which we tried

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Which gave this error

> /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst:Py3 compile:not found 
> Dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal(--configure):
> Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
> Errors were encountered while processing python3-minimal

But I am not able to reinstall python3 as it again shows the error. I feel this is a loop of errors which I am not able to get out of.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You ran "sudo apt-get -f install" when you were asked to run "apt -f install".

Comment: Sorry for the mistake it was a typo. Since I wrote these errors manually from the phone.

Comment: Check the suggestions in the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962402/dpkg-error-pycompile-not-found